# Use repository.save to save items to postgres on wildfly

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jboss, wildfly

I am trying to save to my db with repository.save and i keep getting null pointer exception. Here's my code

> DataModel

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "nlp")
@Resource(name = "datasources/PostgresDS",mappedName = "datasources/PostgresDS")
public class ServiceStatus implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "servicecode")
    private int servicecode;

    @Column(name = "servicename")
    private String servicename;

    @Column(name = "status")
    private String status;

    @Column(name = "reason")
    private String reason;

    @Column(name = "date")
    private String date;

    protected ServiceStatus() {
    }

    public ServiceStatus(int servicecode, String servicename, String status, String reason, String date) {
        this.servicecode = servicecode;
        this.servicename = servicename;
        this.status = status;
        this.reason = reason;
        this.date = date;

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("ServiceStatus[servicecode='%d', servicename='%s', status='%s', reason='%s', date='%s']", servicecode, servicename, status, reason, date);
    }
}
```

> Interface

```
public interface CustomerRepo extends CrudRepository<ServiceStatus, Long> {
    List<ServiceStatus> findByLastName(String lastName);
}
```

> Controller

```
 @RequestMapping("/save")
    public String process() throws IOException, ParseException {
 repository.save(new ServiceStatus(1,"bad","boy","seyi","2017/01/17"));
       }
```

> DataSource
>
> I have also set datasource in standalone.xml

What am i missing please ? it works perfectly on spring boot

Comment: can you show us the full error please

Comment: null pointer exception

Comment: show us the full error please

Comment: Could you post the full stack trace to help? And Btw, what does _it works perfectly on spring boot_ means?